# Div's refuse to be vertically stacked close to each other

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I am having an issue with my CSS and HTML I believe and can not find a workaround. I am trying to have a set of 6 divs holding images at the top of the page, a div with just text in it, with a set 3 divs wide just below that, with a mixture of text and images each. What is currently happening is the top 6 blocks display correctly at the top, then there is a large blank space with the sets of 3 divs below that. The text that is supposed to be between them does not display at all. My HTML code is:

```
<div class="page">
<a href="/menu/kale-grain-bowls"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 kale-grain-bowls">Kale & Grain Bowls</div></a>
<a href="/menu/salads"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 salads">Salads</div></a>
<a href="/menu/burgers-sandwiches"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 burgers-sandwiches">Burgers & Sandwiches</div></a>
<a href="/menu/sides"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 sides">Sides</div></a>
<a href="/menu/smoothies-shakes"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 smoothies-milkshake">Smoothies & Milkshakes</div></a>
<a href="/menu/kids-real-meals"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 kids-real-meals">Kid's Real Meals</div></a>
<div class="menu-type>Kale & Grain Bowls</div>
<div class="foodcontent">
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="kale-grain-bowls/spicy-avocado-lime"><div class="spicy-avocado-lime">SPICY AVOCADO & LIME</div></a>
<div class="textblock">kale, sautéed veggies, avocado, black beans, corn, grape tomato, queso fresco, lime, cilantro, chipotle puree, red pepper vinaigrette</div></div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="kale-grain-bowls/toasted-almond-ginger"><div class ="toasted-almond-ginger">TOASTED ALMOND & GINGER</div </a>
<div class="textblock">kale, sautéed veggies, bok choy, tamari almonds, red cabbage, enoki mushrooms, mint, toasted almond-ginger sauce</div></div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="kale-grain-bowls/local-apple-bacon"><div class="local-apple-bacon-bowl">LOCAL APPLE & BACON BOWL</div></a>
<div class="textblock">kale, avocado, NH slab bacon, local apples, cherries, dried cranberries, sunflower seeds, scallions, red wine vinegar, olive oil</div </div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="kale-grain-bowls/power-bowl"><div class="power-bowl">POWER BOWL</div></a>
<div class="textblock">kale, sesame carrots, Brussels sprouts, crunchy chickpeas, pepitas, local egg, tomato vinaigrette</div></div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="kale-grain-bowls/farmstand-  tomato-basil"><div class="farmstand-tomato-basil">FARMSTAND TOMATO-BASIL</div></a>
<div class="textblock">kale, yellow & green beans, corn, heirloom tomatoes,     grilled halloumi cheese, lima beans, Kalamata olives, sunflower seeds, basil    vinaigrette</div>
</div></div></div>
```

My css is:

```
    .foodblock{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 400px;
    bottom: 50px;
}
.textblock{
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu-type{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
.spicy-avocado-lime{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.toasted-almond-ginger{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.local-apple-bacon-bowl{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.power-bowl{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.farmstand-tomato-basil{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.foodcontent{
    bottom: 500px;
}
```

Please help if you have any idea what could be causing this issue.

Comment: I suggest using developer tools / firebug etc to inspect the element so you can see right away where that blank space is coming.. I bet it's one of these three options: margin, padding, line-height

Comment: I have inspected the element on the page and I have gained no new knowledge. All it tells me is that it is part of the page div which the whole page is a part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of errors and missing brackets in your HTML. I've cleaned it up and threw it in a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7gohamt3/

For example you were missing closing quotes on this line:

```
<div class="menu-type>Kale & Grain Bowls</div>
```

This should fix your problems.

Comment: Thank you, for the help, this has worked, some other things have moved around since I apparently missed some CSS to copy over but that is an easy fix

Comment: Ok so apparently this fix does not transfer to other pages well I am going to keep investigating the issue.

Comment: I also can still not move the text div up to be closer to the top sets of div's which has proven hard to bug test due to all the separated CSS.

Comment: When I applied your HTML to my site and edited the CSS to make it look proper again due to shifts with the menu-type div now existing and applied the HTML changes that were uniform to ever page it broke every page except the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is about "Kale & Grain Bowls" not being displayed. If so, close the quotes for property `class`

```
<div class="menu-type">Kale & Grain Bowls</div>
```

There are problems with closing of div tags at 2 other places

```
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="kale-grain-bowls/toasted-almond-ginger"><div class ="toasted-almond-ginger">TOASTED ALMOND & GINGER</div> </a>

<div class="textblock">kale, avocado, NH slab bacon, local apples, cherries, dried cranberries, sunflower seeds, scallions, red wine vinegar, olive oil</div> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had closed everything properly but apparently not

Comment: I have closed these errors for this page, but I still can not move the bottom divs towards the top. I also now have errors on other pages that I assume is due to this div closing issue being an issue across more than just this one page but I can not find them still.

Comment: I have restored my old code and then fixed the menu-type tag to be functional again. I now have my top divs displaying inline again but I can not find what problem with closing tags you are saying is an issue near the toasted almond ginger div. I also still can not move the bottom sets of divs up towards the top set

Comment: I have finally found and corrected those closing tag errors, My issue still stands where I can not move my divs up

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the foodblick creating geometry well below the ingredients list, try setting the height:auto so the div conforms to the size of the content rather than a discrete px value.

```
.foodblock{
    height:auto;
    /* rest of declarations */
{
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x1x6gjw4/

Comment: I'm currently trying to undo the previous fix but will test this one once things are working again. I was not referring to the ingredients list I was referring to the divs with the col-2 tag.